# Animating multiple axes with matplotlib, only update graph when new data arrives

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data stored in stock_data in JSON format (which can be any arbitrary data). I want to plot 4 axes, and WHEN there is new data, update the graph (through animate I am assuming).

I only want this to occur when using INTRADAY data (as you can see I have an if intraday check at the bottom). I am pulling this intraday data from an API. This API updates every minute or so, and only during certain hours. I don't mind if it doesn't update instantly, but ideally within a 1 minute period of new data.

I have tried pulling new data and comparing it to the old DF (as you can see at the end of the code) and putting it in a while True: loop, however the graph fails to render. I have tried simply putting the entire function in a loop and rendering the graph every time - this not only takes ages to render, but if I am zoomed in on the graph, it completely resets it. I figure this is a problem with redrawing?

Finally, I am unsure what to put in the animation.FuncAnimation() either.. I have excluded ax3 and ax4 because they'll act the same as ax2 for demonstration purposes. Help is much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import numpy as np

## CANDLESTICK GRAPH ## 
def candlestick(symbol, MA1 = 20, MA2 = 200):
    try:
        ## arbitrary colors ##
        candle_upcol = '#cccccc'
        candle_downcol = '#cccccc'
        fill_col = '#cccccc'
        bg_col = '#cccccc'
        spine_col = '#cccccc'
        ## load stocks ##
        stock_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.load(open('db/AAPL.txt')), orient = 'index', dtype = np.float64)
        stock_data = stock_data.values
        ## BEGIN PLOTTING ##
        start_point = len(stock_data[max(MA1, MA2)-1:])
        fig = plt.figure(facecolor=bg_col)
        #set grids
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,4), (1,0), rowspan = 5, colspan = 4, facecolor = bg_col)
        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8,4), (7,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4, sharex = ax1, facecolor= bg_col)
        ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8,4), (0,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4, sharex = ax1, facecolor = bg_col)
        ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((8,4), (6,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4, sharex = ax1, facecolor = bg_col)

        #PRICE plot (AX1)
        candlestick_ohlc(ax1, stock_data[-start_point:,0:5], width = 0.6, colorup = candle_upcol, colordown = candle_downcol)
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
        ax1.grid(True)
        plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False) #remove x ticks

        #MOVING AVERAGES plot (AX1)
        if MA1 != 0:
            av1 = moving_average(stock_data[:,4], MA1) #using close prices
            label_ma1 = '{MA} SMA'.format(MA = str(MA1))
            ax1.plot(stock_data[-start_point:,0], av1[-start_point:], label = label_ma1, color = '#aec6cf', linewidth = .8)
        if MA2 != 0:
            av2 = moving_average(stock_data[:,4], MA2) #using close prices
            label_ma2 = '{MA} SMA'.format(MA = str(MA2))
            ax1.plot(stock_data[-start_point:,0], av2[-start_point:], label = label_ma2, color = '#ffb347', linewidth = .8)
        if MA1 != 0 or MA2 != 0:
            ax1.text(0, 1, 'MA ({MA1}, {MA2})'.format(MA1 = str(MA1), MA2 = str(MA2)), va = 'top', ha = 'left', color = 'w', transform = ax1.transAxes, alpha = 0.5, fontweight = 'bold')

        #VOLUME plot (AX2)
        volume_min = 0 #stock_data[:,5].min()
        ax2.plot(stock_data[-start_point:,0], stock_data[-start_point:,5], '#00ffe8', linewidth = .8)
        ax2.fill_between(stock_data[-start_point:,0], volume_min, stock_data[-start_point:,5], facecolor = fill_col, alpha = 0.5)
        ax2.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([]) #remove y ticks
        ax2.text(0, 1, 'VOLUME', va = 'top', ha = 'left', color = 'w', transform = ax2.transAxes, alpha = 0.5, fontweight = 'bold')

        #RSI plot (AX3)
        #similar to VOL

        #MACD plot (AX4)
        #similar to VOL

        #SHARED plot (ALL AX)
        for all_ax in (ax1, ax2''', ax3, ax4'''):
            plt.setp(all_ax.spines.values(), color=spine_col)
            all_ax.tick_params(axis='both', colors = 'w')
            all_ax.yaxis.label.set_color("w")
            all_ax.yaxis.tick_right()
            all_ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=9)
            all_ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=9)

        #ENTIRE plot
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0)
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
        fig.suptitle('{STOCK}'.format(STOCK = symbol), color = 'w', fontweight='bold', alpha = 0.75)
        print('Drawing graph.')
        if data_type != 'Intraday':
            print('Graphing complete.')
        else:
            #this will be replaced by an API fetch function at some point, this is just for testing if animation works.. needs a sleep function? and while True loop..?
            new_stock_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.load(open('db/AAPL_new.txt')), orient = 'index', dtype = np.float64)
            new_stock_data = new_stock_data.values

            if (new_stock_data[-1] == stock_data[-1]).all() == False:
                stock_data = np.vstack([stock_data, new_stock_data[-1]])

            #ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, '''???''', interval = 10000) #blit=True?
        plt.show()
    except:
        print('Failed main loop.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FuncAnimation` will draw (or blit) repeatedly at a rate given by the `interval`. In case that is not desired, one could use a timer instead. The timer calls a function that will, depending on some condition either do nothing, or update the plot with new data. This way you make sure to only draw the canvas when new data is available (i.e. condition is true).

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t = []
x = []
line, = ax.plot_date(t,x, ls="-")

def update():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if np.random.rand() > 0.9:
        t.append(now)
        x.append(np.random.randn())
        line.set_data(t,x)
        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale_view()
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        message = "new data drawn"
    else:
        message = "no new data"
    print(now.time(), message)


timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=200)
timer.add_callback(update)
timer.start()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very useful! Do you have any idea on how to update the candlesticks from mpl_finance? Given each candlestick is it's own 'line' (from what I gather), I can't do, for example: ln1, = candlestick_ohlc(ax1, stock_data[-start_point:,0:5], width = 0.6), nor can I append it

Comment: When I say append: I will append the stock_data, then I set_data for the lines.. However for the bar graph and candlesticks I am at a loss!

Comment: It's really hard to update a candlestick from mpl_finance. One would probably rather clear the axes and redraw it.

Comment: Makes sense, I will update the candlestick axis by clearing it. What about a bar graph?

Comment: Additionally, whilst the logic makes sense, I am not too sure if this answers my question entirely. You simply call  if np.random.rand() > 0.9, whereas I am checking if (new_stock_data[-1] == stock_data[-1]).all() == False and need to append my dataframe with the new data to stop an infinite pull new data loop. Calling stock_data = np.vstack([stock_data, new_stock_data[-1]]) within the function does not update my dataframe outside of the function..!

Comment: A bar graph is easy to update if the number of bars is unchanged, and only their height or positions changes. This does not seem to be the case here. Hence, clearing is also useful in that case. Concerning the assignment of a global variable inside a local function, check python's `global` statement.